# Що ж означає слово "зюзя"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Недавно прочитала статтю **["П’яний в зюзю співробітник львівської поліції на смерть збив велосипедистку"](https://korupciya.com/p-yaniy-v-zyuzyu-spivrobitnik-lvivskoyi-politsiyi-na-smert-zbiv-velosipedistku/)**. І все ж зацікавило саме значення слова **"зюзя"**. Зазирнула у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zjuzja) - інформації не знайшла.

То що ж означає слово ***зюзя***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Зюзя](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8F) (Мороз, Морозко) — божество холоду, віхоли, криги у давніх слов'ян

[Тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8F) написано, що Е. Е. Левкиевская вважає, що Зюзя, як самостійний персонаж, є винаходом кабінетної міфології, який був невідомий язичникам.

Існує друге значення слова зюзя - п'яний, брудний, неохайний чоловік, якого порівнюють зі свинею. Утворено слово від вигуків «зю-зю», «зюсь-зюсь», «зюрь-зюрь». З цим значенням пов'язані вирази «п'яний як зюзя» і «назюзюкався», а також «і сам він зюзя зюзей», - відгук про нечепуру, простувату людину.

Comment: Також співзвучно з [дюдя](http://sum.in.ua/s/djudja), але тут таки інше значення.